# D3 + ReactJs Integration

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-router

I was trying to integrate some D3 code (v4) with reactjs.

This my d3 code:.

http://plnkr.co/edit/K3YNrZQXApZLQmPJNIEN?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .background {
        fill: none;
    }

    .feature {
        fill: #ccc;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .feature.active {
        fill: orange;
    }

    .mesh {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke-linejoin: round;
    }
</style>

<body>

        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    active = d3.select(null);


var zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", stopped, true);




var g = svg.append("g");

svg.call(zoom);
g.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", reset);

g.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 10)
  .attr("cx", 200)
  .attr("cy", 200)
  .on("click", clicked);


function clicked(d) {
            console.log('clicked')
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

   var bbox = this.getBBox();
       scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(3, 0.9 / Math.max(bbox.width / width, bbox.height / height))),
       translate = [width / 2 - scale * bbox.x, height / 2 - scale * bbox.y];

   svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call( zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0],translate[1]).scale(scale) ); // updated for d3 v4
}

function reset() {
            active.classed("active", false);
          active = d3.select(null);

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call( zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity ); // updated for d3 v4
}

function zoomed() {
            g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.transform.k + "px");
          g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform); // updated for d3 v4
}

function stopped() {
  if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) d3.event.stopPropagation();
}

        </script>
```

So it provides a zoom/pan svg and if you click the dot it will zoom in to the bbox.

I hope to create a react component to wrap these d3 code and also could be used with react-router.

Inside this react component I hope the dom events could be captured (e.g. click), and call the zoom/reset methods.

I found some example such as 
    http://bl.ocks.org/sxywu/1db896c1a38d89ae71b4

but I am quite new to react, struggling to understand what is the correct and easy way to achieve this.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

React + d3 is a very tough subject because of the nature of d3 wanting to directly manipulate the DOM, and react not liking that. React creates and manages a virutal DOM, and whenever d3 wants to directly manipulate the DOM, it breaks. If you're new to React, I would highly recommend not trying to just mash d3 and react together because they do not play nicely together and you will run into bug after bug. If you notice, even the link you provided does not work very nice and has unintended bugs / visual effects (just try dragging one of the nodes). And that person is very experienced with d3.

This isn't to say that it isn't **possible**, just very difficult. I would recommend checking out react-based charting libraries that leverage d3 for some math calculations, but not much more. My personal favorite is [recharts](http://recharts.org/#/en-US/)

I know it's not the best news since d3 is fun to work with, but trust me, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches and grief if you just opt for something simpler like what I've linked. It just works.